# List of figures prefix

Tags: table-of-contents

Hello I want to add a prefix to list of figures. Is there any way how to do it ? I am using `\documentclass[12pt]{article}` and `\usepackage[czech]{babel}`.

[image: Result which I need.]

I have found this solution which helped but not as I wanted to. It showed full name Obrázek instead of Obr. (Figure x Fig.)

```
{%
\let\oldnumberline\numberline%
\renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
\listoffigures%
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It would be great if you could  show us what you have tried. Posting a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that indicates what you are trying to do makes it easier for people to understand what you want. It also makes it easier for people to help you, since they have some code to start from, and hence much more likely that some one will try to help you.

Comment: I've tried this :

Comment: Please use [edit] to add your code to the original post.

Comment: `\figurename` expands to Obr\'azek (using Babel one presumes), so just replace it with `Obr`.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this also using the `tocloft` package. If you're independently using `titlesec` for something, then Vincent's answer is probably to be preferred. Adjust the spacing for the label and number as needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Obr.~}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{5em}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
A figure
\caption{A caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
A figure
\caption{A caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
A figure
\caption{A caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with the `\titlecontents` command from the `titletoc` package (see the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) for more details). For example, with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{figure}[0mm]%
    {\makebox{Obr.~}}%
    {\makebox{\thecontentslabel\quad}}%
    {}%
    {\enspace\dotfill\enspace\thecontentspage}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\caption{A first figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{A second figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Again another figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

we get the following list of figures.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following lines can do the work but the next line of caption is not indented with this method if the caption is longer than one line. How to fix that?

```
{%


\documentclass{article}%

\usepackage[czech]{babel}%

\usepackage{titletoc}%

\titlecontents{figure}[0mm]%

    {\makebox{Obr.~}}%
    {\makebox{\thecontentslabel\quad}}%
    {}%
    {\enspace\dotfill\enspace\thecontentspage}


}
```

Comment: Please raise this question individually and delete this reply.